# Aggregate rating google rich snippet not working

Tags: google-search, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I'm trying to add the google rating script to my website but when i search for my website in google it doesn't display the rating script.

I tested my website with the structed data testing tool and it didn't display any errors.

I also crawled the page with the google webmaster tool.

The html:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
    <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Kindred Realms" />
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="28-1-2014" />
    <meta itemprop="keywords" content="rate, website, game, datop100" />
    <div class="topMenu">
        <h1 itemprop="name" content="Live website version">
            <a href="http://datop100.com" itemprop="url">Live website version</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="bannerImage" id="pageBanner">
            <img itemprop="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/xzldkIZ.png">
            <p itemprop="description">This is just a description for the development website.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="horizontalBar"></div>
        <div id="voteContainerRating">
            <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
                </div>
                <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
                <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="3" />
                <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="3" />
                <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1" />
                <div id="ratingInfo">
                    <img src="/Themes/LightBlue/Content/images/rating/3 _Star-Rating.png" alt="2,7 Star Rating">
                    <p id="ratingDesc">
                        Rating: <span itemprop="ratingValue">2,7</span>/5 - 3 votes
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Structured data testing tool:

[image]

Comment: While testing your code, I get an error: "Failed to normalize the rating value." in the testing tool. Not sure what causing this error to me and not to you. Could you pls share the url if the code is live.

Comment: from your screenshot you are telling it to show 'item4' as having an aggregate rating of 3, based on 3 ratings, where the minimum possible rating is 2 and the maximum is 3.
Your **highestRating** and **lowestRating** are probably wrong, "The highest value allowed in this rating system. If bestRating is omitted, 5 is assumed" etc - although this is probably not the issue

Comment: the code does not validate with variables in it, please post the code as seen by Fetch as Google (from the DOM). Also your screenshot has **item4** as the itemReviewed, but your code has **@Model.WebsiteTitle** as itemReviewed

Comment: The url: http://dev.datop100.com/Website/View/Jamieknoef/1 (loading may take a few seconds because the application pool has to start up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems.

1. Your code is rating a website called "Test 4", and "Test 4" appears *both* as `name` and `itemReviewed` (the latter isn't needed). You need to show *what* type of Thing you are actually rating, e.g. Restaurant, Computer Game, Movie, Product etc. You should include quite a lot of information about the thing you are rating if you want to get a high SEO e.g. Author/Creator of what you are reviewing and age rating.
2. The star rating is worked out by google, it displays `ratingValue` (your aggregate score, normally a decimal rather than a whole number) in comparison to `bestRating` (and taking into account `lowestRating`. So your code now gives a rating of **3 out of 3, with a minimum score of 2** which doesn't make much sense - I think that is why the Stars and rating don't show. Instead set `highestRating` to 5 (for example) and `lowestRating` to `1`, that should give a **Rating 3/10** in the snippet shown.
3. When testing include the name of the item if your search, a page may rate many different items. Usually having the word 'rating' in your search criteria should help. You can already see the snippet changes when you do this eg https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:datop100.com+test+4+rating

Here is a Schema.org example for `VideoGame`, which is a type of `CreativeWork`

```
<body vocab="http://schema.org/" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoGame http://schema.org/MobileApplication">
<span itemprop="gamePlatform">iOS</span>
<img itemprop="image" alt="Picture of monopoly board game." src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/56/85/9b/56859be5-c5fa-9cc2-9277-276891ad070e/screen568x568.jpeg"/>
<span itemprop="name">MONOPOLY</span> by <span itemprop="author">Electronic Arts</span>
<span itemprop="description">**YOU VOTED & THE CAT’S OUT OF THE BAG** Thanks to the votes from YOU and thousands of loyal MONOPOLY Facebook fans from 185 different countries, the CAT mover is now available to play with in this latest update as well as in the classic board game version of MONOPOLY!</span>
<div itemprop="aggregateRating"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
<span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> stars -
<span itemprop="reviewCount">33</span> reviews
```

Comment: I added all the information i got into the microdata. I changed the rating values. Also added more visible data to the user. Unfortunately still no rating script in the search results. I edited my first post with the new info.

Comment: You are still rating a website, not a game (however the rating should show *if* you change **2,7** to **2.7** for `ratingValue`. Separate the WebSite and VideoGame microdata if you want to rate a videogame. After changing it you need to do Fetch as google then wait 2-3 days at least for it to pick it up

Comment: They are game websites, so websites is the right microdata. I just noticed that google picked it up. Unfortunately still no rating script, any ideas of what could be wrong? (https://www.google.nl/#q=site:http:%2F%2Fdev.datop100.com+2.7+Star+Rating)

Comment: Try Fetch as Google again -  google still shows the comma not the decimal for 2.7, but is clearly understanding it and added the words "Star Rating" that aren't on your page- I see ** Links. Test. Test 4. My desc. 2,7 Star Rating. Rating: 2,7/5 - 3 votes. Reviews. Rate. Statistics. Daily. Average. Today. Yesterday. 1-9-2015. 31-8-2015. 30-8- 2015.**

Comment: Game websites would be better covered by http://schema.org/VideoGame - all the properties of WebSite are inherited from CreativeWork, and VideoGame contains all of these too, but allows more specific information like characters, the number of players, quest etc. It's generally better to use more specific schemas rather than general ones like website, and it's more likely that people would search for Game or VideoGame than WebSite when looking for reviews. (VideoGame is a type of http://schema.org/Game which is electronic rather than soccer for example Basically it's a one word change

Comment: @Jamie Star Rating now shows in [structured data linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/?url=http:%2F%2Fdev.datop100.com%2FWebsite%2FView%2FJamieknoef%2F1) but at the end it mentions an issue with the <body>. They may not be showing in google results because the WebSite schema isn't considered a valid product or service - [extra guidelines](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#aggregate_ratings) and the name of the item reviewed  'Live website version - short title' may not be seen as a proper product.Try a rarer/less programming sounding `name` property

Comment: i've updated all the info. Still sticked with the website scheme because the site is going to be a public cms, in my example it's a topsite for game servers but it can be used for anything. Let's give google some time to figure it out.

Comment: @Jamie using 2-3 days after re-fetching in google seems to show the results. You could use http://schema.org/CreativeWork for *any* intangible item and http://schema.org/Product for anything physical. If the purpose is to make a plug-in then a parameter can be used for the user to choose between them. WebSite of course is a type of CreativeWork.

Comment: @Jamie google has now picked up the new Product schema and the correct details. The star rating isn't showing, I think this is because the `brand` is set to your name, which is sees as the manufacter or Kindred Realms. Put this in a separate http://schema.org/Organization schema. The other issue is that the URL of the *product* should uniquely identify the product - either link to the manufacter's page, a wikipedia or other page about Kindred Realms, or remove it. At the moment it looks (to google) like you are rating another page in your own website -a page not about Kindred Realms on it.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. I've linked to an internal page which redirects it to the homepage of Kindred Realms. The name of the organization has been set to the title (Kindred Realm) at the moment. I've submitted a new crawl request to google.

Comment: it may not like the redirect

Comment: The redirect is kinda essential for my software. I hope google accepts the redirect, if it wont accept it i will recode the program a bit to remove the redirect

Comment: its working! Thanks a lot for the help, really appreciate it.